# Normalize -1 ~ 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

there are many ways about normalize skils for ml and dl. It is known to provide only normalization for 0 to 1.
I want to know that is some ways to normalize -1 between 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `min-max scalar` or the `z-score normalization` here is what u can do in sklearn

`from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler`

`from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`

or hard code it like this

`x_scaled = (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) * 2 - 1` -> this one for minmaxscaler

`x_scaled = (x - mean(x)) / std(x)` -> this one for standardscaler

Comment: It is really helpful for me. additionaly, can you explain about denormalization equation?

Comment: its just the reverser of the aove equeations (almost..)


```x = x_norm * (max(x) - min(x)) + min(x)``` --> this one for minmaxscaler

```x = x_norm * std(x) + mean(x)``` --> this one for standardscaler

Answer (score 2):

Consider re-scale the normalized value. e.g. normalize to 0..1, then multiply by 2 and minus 1 to have the value fall into the range of -1..1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler) from `sklearn` and specify the range:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.random(10)})
df['std'] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['val']])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        val       std
0  0.630673 -0.080580
1  0.842867  0.563090
2  0.662732  0.016669
3  0.433478 -0.678750
4  0.778883  0.369001
5  0.327573 -1.000000  # MIN
6  0.512345 -0.439515
7  0.563789 -0.283465
8  0.986901  1.000000  # MAX
9  0.775790  0.359619
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to normalize data to the range between -1 and 1. One common method is called Min-Max normalization. It works by transforming the data to a new range, such that the minimum value is mapped to -1 and the maximum value is mapped to 1. The formula for this normalization is:

x_norm = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min) * 2 - 1

Where x_norm is the normalized value, x is the original value, x_min is the minimum value in the data and x_max is the maximum value in the data.

Another method for normalizing data to the range between -1 and 1 is called Z-score normalization, also known as standard score normalization. This method normalizes the data by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. The formula for this normalization is:

x_norm = (x - mean) / standard deviation

Where x_norm is the normalized value, x is the original value, mean is the mean of the data and standard deviation is the standard deviation of the data.